# I get an error when I declare a new variable in the function argument : Why is that?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, syntax-error

For a function with an argument :

```
function displayCouplet(var couplet) {
   document.write(couplet);
}

displayCouplet("The object of my worship lies beyond perception's reach,For men who see, the Ka'aba is a compass, nothing more.");
```

displays an error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var* . Why is that ? If I omit the keyword `var` from the argument,then it goes fine. Please explain why is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two parted.

First off, you're trying to declare a `function` using the keyword `var`.
This is faulty.

The proper way is

```
function displayCouplet(couplet) {
    //write your body here
}
```

Secondly defining variables aren't done in the function arguments, its done within the function body.
Again, the proper way is

```
function displayCouplet(couplet) {
    //write your body here
    var myOtherCouplet = "whateverACoupletIs";
}
```

EDIT:

An argument passed to the function is created, implicitly, as local variable in your function.

```
function displayCouplet(couplet) {
    //write your body here
    var myOtherCoupletCopy = couplet;
}
```

New variables that you want in your function should be declared with `var`, omitting the `var` keyword will create a global variable.

And succintly you call this function as you have already figured out. :)

Comment: why don't we declare a var in the function argument ? Isn't it that a new variable is created when I call function by value ?

Comment: No, that argument is created, implicitly, as local variable in your function when you pass it. Only new variables that you want in your function should be declared with `var`, omitting the `var`keyword will create a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `var`. Function parameters implicitly become local variables.
And you declare a function with `function` not `var`

```
function displayCouplet(couplet) {
   document.write(couplet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first `var` to `function` and remove the second `var`, then it should work!